# How do you add an ldap group to a system user?

Tags: user-accounts, rhel-6, openldap

The question is basically the same as : [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/351794/cannot-add-ldap-group-to-system-local-user)

I am unable to add a ldap group to a system user. This does not work :

```
usermod -a -G ldapGroup systemUser
```

The same with gpasswd command.

The other way around works :

```
usermod -a -G systemGroup ldapUser
```

It works for the main group :

```
usermod -g ldapGroup systemUser
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Unix, primary group is a property of the user, but the secondary groups aren't. In other words, you don't add secondary groups to users; you add the user as a member of the group.

So the problem here is that `usermod` simply does not know how to modify LDAP groups.

However, *depending on the system configuration,* you may be able to work around this by creating a *local* group with the same name and GID (`groupadd --gid … --non-unique`), as the member lists might just be concatenated together. Then add the user as a group member locally.

Comment: Note that (If the groupname already exists in an external group database such as NIS or LDAP, groupadd will deny the group creation request)[http://linux.die.net/man/8/groupadd].